# Допустимо ли создавать объекты в методах класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Есть [троллерская паста](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0:Hello,_world!#PHP) на которую я случайно наткнулся. Не стоит воспринимать код всерьёз. Посмотрел, а там объекты создаются в методах класса. Сам никогда так не делал, объекты передаю в конструктор или сеттер, создавая их заранее.

У меня появился вопрос. Даже два.

- На сколько правильно создавать объекты в методах и какие принципы это нарушает?
- Считается ли такое поведение "фабрикой"?

Comment: Хорошие у вас вопросы возникают. Рекомендую ко всему прочему познакомиться с парадигмой [инверсии управления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Инверсия_управления).

Comment: @vp_arth то чувство, когда одна ссылка даёт понять многие моменты, и пропадает смысл отвечать... :₽

Comment: На самом деле ссылки недостаточно для новичка. Вы интерпретируете содержимое с высоты своего опыта, которого у новичков нет. Поэтому отвечать смысл есть.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на первый вопрос.

**Это не правильно!** Дело в том что, создания объектов внутри других классов, полностью рушит масштабируемость и в целом делает ваш код менее безопасным и более запутанным,а также более зависимым от внешней стреды, так например если класс из которого мы пытаемся получить объект не существует в нашей области видимости, нам потребуется переписать архитектуру и сложить области видимости, или напрямую вызывать класс из области видимости, В итоге, так делать не правильно, это путает разработчиков, и делает код менее понятным, это абсолютное нарушения одного из самых популярных и стандартных паттернов под названием "внедрение зависимостей" - `DI`, прочтите про него, [вот](https://habr.com/post/191168/).

Нет, такое поведение считается плохим не масштабируемым и зависимым, небезопасным и не очень профессиональным кодом.

UPD: также уточню, если вы и правда создавали объекты заранее, и передавил их в конструктор например, вы вероятно как раз следовали `DI`, соответственно ваш код на порядок лучше в этом плане, чем тот который вы представили на осмотр.

Comment: Хорошо. Я думаю так же. Ведь получается что класс использующий такой подход, становится зависим от класса, объект которого он создает и, например, при изменении имени класса создаваемого объекта, придется менять имя и в методе, который его создает. Но на счёт вашего второго высказывания есть сомнения. В [порождающих шаблонах проектирования](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Creational/README.html) сказано, что все фабрики создают объекты внутри себя. Это имеет смысл, потому что фабрике делегируют функции создания объектов, это её прямое назначение.

Comment: @Петр честно говоря, за счет того что я с телефона, я не рассматривал весь код который вы представили, но в том отрывке который я увидел, я не увидел реализации фабрики как таковой.

Comment: Класс `HelloWorldStrategyFactory`. Вообще у меня возник небольшой диссонанс. Когда вы описываете класс, который должен создать объект внутри себя, как вы это делаете? Я запрашиваю через параметры конструктора объект фабрики/DI и создаю объект через метод этого посредника

Comment: Если следовать `DI`, то в параметрах какого-либо метода, мы запрашиваем уже созданный объект а потом его заносим в свойства нашего класса, или же у объекта который мы запрашиваем есть специальное свойство для возврата нового объекта с параметрами которые нам нужны. Ну например нам понадобилось в свойство класса поместить особый объект при этом создать его нужно с параметрами которые мы получаем в конструкторе, для это мы опять же передаем готовый объект конструктору а тот через специальный метод объекта который мы передали, создает новый объект с заданными параметрами.

Comment: "или же у объекта который мы запрашиваем есть специальное свойство для возврата нового объекта с параметрами которые нам нужны", это и есть посредничество. Вопрос в том, как тот объект создает новый? Надеюсь, отвечая вы не пытались специально уклониться от этого вопроса. Если нужны ассоциации, представьте класс `UserManager`. У вас есть метод `delete`, возвращающий булевый тип, а есть методы `create` и `get`, возвращающие объект класса `User`, как они создают этот объект?

Comment: Я говорил немного о другом, но в прочем, именно в такой архитетуре как раз обьект класса `UserManager` Мы передаем в конструктор класса который нам нужен, а уже там может брать параметры из конструктора и создавать новый обьект с этими параметрами с помощью метода `create` С параметром `user`, в методе мы как раз берем жтот параметр и создаем на основе него обьект. Таким образом мы соблюдаем `DI`.

Comment: Добавлю свои 5 копеек - DI конкретного класса - тоже зависимость. Везде, где возможно, нужно инжектить интерфейсы, а не конкретные классы.

Comment: Отличные пять копеек!:)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов не понял вас. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте комментарий или напишите ещё раз, как метод `create` класса `UserManager` из примера выше создает объект. На сколько я понял, вы написали что требуете в конструкторе класса, имя класса/интерфейса из которого будет создан объект класса `User`. Я правильно понял что вы хотели донести? Если это так, то получается, что если нам понадобится создать объект класса `UserManager` в `SimpleObject`, то в его конструктор придется передать имя класса/интерфейса `UserManager`, а так же его зависимости (Имя для создания `User` в данном случае)

Comment: Извините если отвечаю не очень подробно, комментарии ограничены. Просто скажу по порядку, у нашего `N` Класса есть конструктор с параметрами `objName`, `manager`,  и например `message`, внутри класса мы используем уже созданный переданный в параметры объект `manager` И его метод `generate`, в этот метод мы передаём `objName` И после этого метод создаст класс с именем `objName`, при этом мы можем туда передать например ещё `message` И этот параметр приймит конструктор объекта `objName`, соответсвенно метод вернёт нам новй объект `objName`. Надеюсь понятно выразился.

Comment: Подобные цепочки, сколько бы длинными они не были, решаются инъектором, объектом который знает о всех зависимостях, верно? Но тогда возникает ещё один вопрос. Как `SimpleObject` обращается к инъектору? Варианта тут как минимум 3. 1) создает объект инъектора внутри, 2) обращается к глобальной области видимости через статику (`Injector::create('name')`), 3) получает объект инъектора в конструкторе. Последний - самый адекватный, но что тогда получается, вся цепочка должна запрашивать в конструкторе объект инъектора? Ведь только так возможно обеспечить исполнение DI, не прибегая к global

Comment: Сейчас попробую разобраться с вашим последним сообщением, а вы пока что ответьте на 2 последних моих, это очень важно для моего понимания

Comment: Дело в том что моментов на таком этапе становиться слишком много, и они уже частично выходят за понимания паттернов. Дело в том что, фабрики например, не ограничивают нас на завистимости. А совмещение фабрики и зависимостей вызывает ещё десяток других вопросов. Человек из комментариев к вашему вопрос скинул ссылку, прочитайте про `loC`, вообще в целом, он даст ответы на многие вопросы. Ибо мое понимание совмещения `DI` И фабрик заканчивается на том что я описал вам в последнем сообщени. Далее я не углублялся.

Comment: @Петр, ничего плохого в зависимости UserManager от User нет. Оба  эти класса считаются client-space классами. По большому счёту - это его назначение - создавать вам юзеров. Всё нужно применять с умом, без фанатизма. Где-то Вам всё равно придётся написать `new`, просто желательно это делать в неком `ServiceLocator/Injector/IoCContainer/ClassLoader`, кто как называет. Его инстанс вы передаёте в конструктор класса приложения в точке входа. Ни в коем случае не делайте его глобально доступным(Singleton), я неоднократно сталкивался с необходимостью иметь одновременно несколько контейнеров.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов Дело в том, что на практике IoC реализуется не руками, а например, как DI (IoC-контейнеры). Ну не будете же вы вручную все это создавать. А мы сейчас именно это и обсуждаем. Обсуждаем подход к реализации внедрения зависимостей. Мы пришли к необходимости инъектора и у меня остался последний, самый значимый вопрос, "как вы представляете себе внедрение инъектора?", на который вы все не хотите дать ответа. Но все в порядке, вы мне ничего не должны. Но если кто-то зайдет в этот вопрос и прочитает этот комментарий: Привет, ответь на этот вопрос, если знаешь ответ. Спрашивать не стыдно

Comment: @vp_arth здравствуйте. Если речь идет о самодостаточном модуле, например библиотеке, то всё так. На самом деле конечному пользователю даже не обязательно знать как устроена библиотека, потому что её поддержкой занимается не он. Но я за строгое соблюдение паттернов и свой код я хочу писать так, что бы его было легко изучать и изменять любому человеку не знакомому со мной. Я хочу придерживаться строгих стандартов и делать код максимально предсказуемым. IoC важный принцип и я хочу с ним разобраться. Можете мне помочь? Сделав это публично, вы поможете всем кто столкнется с этой проблемой в будущем

Comment: @Петр, комментарии - незначащая часть этого проекта. Лучше всего - задать новый вопрос "Что такое инверсия управления и как её применять" и кто-то из экспертов(я или/и не я - мне спать пора :) ) ответит вам и всем будущим читателям. Так и пополняется база знаний ruSO. Удачи.

Comment: @vp_arth смотрите, мне не понятно вот что: приложение представляет собой объект (точка входа), один из атрибутов которого содержит инъектор зависимостей в виде объекта. Приложение вызывает контроллеры, передавая в них инъектор. Так, контроллер может создать любой объект известный IoC-контейнеру. Но я не могу понять что делать, когда объекту внутри контроллера (например модели) нужно создать объект. Обратите внимание, создать самостоятельно (не зависимость). Пример такого случая я описал выше. Что делать в этом случае? Требовать в конструкторе `SimpleClass` (см. пример) инъектор?

Comment: @vp_arth спокойной ночи. Я другого мнения. Большую роль в сети играют контекстные ссылки. Если я создам другой вопрос, а новичек вроде меня, которого интересует мой вопрос, наткнется на этот url, он не найдет того, что он искал. О DI написано везде и я знаю что это такое. Вопрос в решении конкретной проблемы. Избежание создания класса внутри объекта без помощи global. Это сообщение я пишу для модераторов, в попытке оправдать длинные комментарии, если они здесь запрещены. Будьте справедливы и не удаляйте здесь ничего. Это последнее сообщение с объяснением "почему не создаю отдельный вопрос"