# Как методы класса должны создавать объекты не нарушая инверсии зависимостей?

Tags: php, ооп

Как посоветовали в [другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822180), создаю новый.

Там я спросил, допустимо ли создавать объекты внутри методов и не нарушает ли это какие-либо принципы, например IoC. Нормального, аргументированного ответа на вопрос я так и не получил, поэтому если вы знаете ответ, можете сходить и туда.

В комментарий на довольно резкий ответ, я задал четкий уточняющий вопрос

> Метод `get` класса `UserManager`, должен вернуть созданный им объект
>   класса `User`.
>
> Как он должен это сделать?

Автор ответа попытался запутать меня и не дал четкого ответа на поставленный вопрос.

Его позиция заключалась в том, что создание объекта внутри метода нарушает принцип инверсии зависимостей, так как метод класса должен знать имя класса создаваемого объекта и как нужно создавать этот объект.

---

Вопрос, выделенный цитированием, остался без ответа, поэтому в первую очередь ответьте на него. Как должен быть устроен класс `UserManager`, что бы его метод `get` смог вернуть, созданный им объект класса `User`?

И есть дополнительный пример.

Представим что у нас есть 3 класса. `UserManager`, `User` и `Controller`.

Метод `test` класса `Controller` должен создать объект `UserManager`, вызвать его метод `get`, а затем, например, вызвать в `var_dump` метод `Foo` полученного объекта `User`.

Как должен быть устроен класс `Controller`?

---

Обратите внимание, эти вопросы о том, как методы классов должны создавать объекты, соблюдая основные паттерны.

Просьба отвечать аргументированно, я буду уточнять все что мне не понятно, не нужно направлять меня на чтение мануалов о паттернах, в ответ на вопрос о конкретных тонкостях их работы, если у вас нет времени или желания помочь разобраться мне в теме, просто проигнорируйте мой вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Понимаете, паттерны проектирования **это не серебрянная пуля**, да они позволяют решать конкретные задачи, но их не стоит применять или стараться применять там, где это не требуется. В начале карьеры, многие программисты стараются использовать паттерны где только можно, но это неправильный путь, так как паттерны хороши только там, где они действительно нужны. Приложение можно написать и без паттернов, и оно будет хорошо работать и может быть предсказуемым и расширяемым.

Я не просто так написал это лирическое отступление, это применимо ко всему.

Действительно, грамотная система **должна зависить от интерфейсов**, а не от конкретной реализации, чтобы поддерживать новые бизнес-требования, но, к сожалению - **это не всегда возможно, да и не совсем нужно**. Полноценные архитектурные границы обходятся дорого, они требуют интерфейсов, структур для выходных и выходных данных и так далее - это требует значительных усилий для поддержки кода, но также и для его создания.

Есть такое понятие, как стабильные классы. Данные классы нет необходимости делать абстрактными, например в **Java** есть класс **String**, определяющий строку, класс очень стабилен, изменения в него вносятся довольно редко и мы можем на него положиться и терпеть данную зависимость, потому что можем положиться на их постоянство. Мы склонны игнорировать надежный фундамент, а **избегать зависимости нужно только от неустойчивых конкретных элементов системы**.

**Сущность** - это объект, определяющий какие-то базовые бизнес правила нашего проекта, эти правила не выполняются сами по себе, они имеют смысл только как часть автоматизированной системы. Вариант использования является объектом,  Сущность ничего не знает о вариантах использования. Вариант использования зависит от сущности, а сущности не зависят от вариантов использования. Сущности - это наше сердце системы, она должна быть максимально стабильна и быть самым независимым кодом в системе.

Если рассмотреть архитектуру и взаимодействие между уровнями, то оно может выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: Архитектура]

Использование в **UserManager** класса User, а следовательно использование конкретного класса не несет в себе особых проблем, так как мы используем стабильную и надежную сущность, явно отображаем что работаем c User, если не будет этой сущности - есть ли смысл в нашей системе? Вряд ли. Здесь мы реализуем вариант использования этой сущности.

Конечно, в вашей системе может быть куча разных типов пользователей и под каждый вы можете определенно создать класс, который бы определял специфичные методы работы, но скорее всего, класс для работы с пользователем у вас будет один. **Если же существует несколько типов сущностей** реализуемый от одной, то конечно требуется определить интерфейс и работать с интерфейсом, а для получения писать методы, которые бы, в случае необходимости, возвращали конкретные экземпляры. Предположим, у вас бы были тип пользователей Client и Administrator, естественно вам нужен абстрактный класс User, который бы определял методы типа getId(), getPassword() и подобные общие методы, которые бы пригодились в других частях системы.

Я рассказывал выше про дороговизну архитектурных границ, архитектор действительно может посчитать, что требуется например сохранить архитектурную границу, но не всегда сохраняют полную границу, можно сохранить только какую-то необходимую часть. Здесь нужно понимать, нужно ли вам это в будущем, не стоит думать теорией "А вдруг мне это пригодится". Здесь можно применить **YAGNI** *(«You aren't gonna need it»; с англ. — «Вам это не понадобится»)*

Не во всех способах получится избегать нарушения принципа инверсии зависимости, но эти проблемы можно сосредоточить в одном месте и изолировать от внешнего использования.

**Гибкая система хороша тем, что гибкая только в тех местах, где это требуется.**

### Вернемся к UserManager

Например, у нас в проекте есть сущность **User**, которая в конструкторе по умолчанию имеет обязательные поля **email** и **password** - это бизнес-правило, без этого нельзя работать с пользователем.

Если рассматривать **UserManager**, то его главное назначение это работа с сущностью **User**, например метод **create(email, password): User**, по сути упрощает нам работу с сущностью, скрывая от клиента интерфейс создания сущности. При работе с внешними уровнями, мне больше нравится название **UserService** (отображает паттерн Service Layer), по сути это Facade.

Получение пользователя и сохранение из базы и в базу должен выполнять **DoctrineUserRepository**, который является некоторой прослойкой между приложением и интерфейсами к базе данных.

Далее, у нас есть **UserController**, который предоставляет клиенту соответствующие методы клиенту.

Представить реализацию можно вот так:

[image: Диаграмма]

Выглядеть это может следующим образом:

```
class UserController extends AuthenticatedUserController 
{  
    protected $userService;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->userService = new UserServiceImpl(new DoctrineUserRepository());
    }

    public function removeUserAction() 
    {
       $this->userService->remove($this->user);
    }

    public function getUserAction($id) 
    {
       return $this->userService->getById($id);
    }
}
```

Конечно, **UserService** можно еще подключать через Dependency Injection.

### Почему мы сделали UserService, как интерфейс?

Да все просто, я в любой момент могу захотеть создать другой UserService, например тестовый, и подставить его в определенные методы.

В коде вы видите жесткую зависимость, но ее как я уже указывал можно вынести в DI. **Я просто показал, как этот сервис создается.**

Хотелось бы заметить, что это лишь один из способов реализации вашей задачи. Способов которые позволяют выполнить данную задачу намного больше, но правильное решение зависит всегда от приложения.

**Необходимо учитывать тонкости вашего приложения, иначе паттерны не спасут.**

### Рекомендуемая литература

*Чистая архитектура. Искусство разработки программного обеспечения. Роберт Мартин
Чистый код. Создание, анализ и рефакторинг. Роберт Мартин*

### Ответы на вопросы

> Меня интересует возможен ли код, в котором не существует неявных
>   зависимостей? Не будем обсуждать целесообразность, просто скажите,
>   возможно это или нет. И если да, то как в этом случае выглядит
>   создание объекта внутри другого объекта. Ведь если класс обязан знать
>   имя класса или его абстракции (интерфейса) то это уже неявная
>   зависимость. Допустим мы используем DI. В этом случае, что бы создать
>   объект вы должны сделать так: (new Injector)->create('className').
>   Всё, класс зависит от Injector. Выхода нет?
>
> Тут можно было бы предложить передавать объект инъектора в
>   конструктор, но вы должны понимать, что в реальном проекте классы
>   превратятся в питоноподобные, где первым аргументом в конструкторе
>   всегда требуется объект инъектора, что делает код неудобным для
>   человека (как обязанность создавать интерфейсы для любых объектов,
>   даже для тех, которые подразумевают единственную реализацию), а значит
>   трудно поддерживаемым. Или разрешить обращение к global, но в этом
>   случае зависимость лишь перекладывается на имя переменной, а не класса
>   + анти-паттерн

**Да, такой код возможен.**

Интерфейс не определяет зависимость, а определяет возможную реализацию, интерфейс не указывает на конкретный класс, а как бы говорит, что для работы нужны такие методы. Благодаря интерфейсу мы зависим от необходимых методов, но никак не зависим от конкретной реализации. Без интерфейсов нельзя обойтись, чтобы работать с чем-то, нужно знать какие у него есть методы или способы, как в реальном мире. Нет определенный способов - нет гарантированной возможности для работы. Да, зависимость (A -> B -> C) между A и C действительно есть, где B интерфейс, но между A и C свободная связь.

Как я указал в ответе, гибкие архитектурные границы обходятся дорого и если вы хотите гибкий код, то придется платить за него временем на проектирование и реализацию.

В случае с DI, существует 2 способа передачи зависимостей, одна из которых прямая инъекция зависимостей через конструктор, а другая - это передача или создание локатора сервисов.

И то, что вы описали про new Injector - это локатор сервисов и это жесткая зависимость. По сути, все сводится к тому, чтобы передавать локатор сервисов везде и из него получать конкретные классы, но этот путь только кажется простым, потом вы за эту простоту заплатите огромную цену при тестировании, когда замучаетесь искать все, что когда-то получали из этого Injector'a и конфигурировать его, и я сам раньше использовал Service Locator, пока не наступил на грабли.

[Передача всего контейнера или Injector'а в класс - это анти-паттерн](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Класс не должен ничего знать о контейнере, только на определенных уровнях (например, инициализации или на крайний случай контроллеров) мы знаем о его существовании, создаваемый класс должен знать только о интерфейсах.

И вот другой способ внедрения зависимостей - это внедрение через конструктор. Этот способ к сожалению действительно тяжелый для неподготовленного специалиста из-за сложности правильного проектирования, потому что, чтобы его грамотно реализовать, нужно соблюдать правило единственной ответственности, ну и остальные принципы **SOLID, DRY, CCP, REP, CRP**, так как придется проектировать классы так, чтобы в них было легко подставлять в идеале по одному компоненту.

Нет ничего плохого в том, что мы знаем на некоторых уровнях приложения о существовании контейнера, предположим, возьмем мой контроллер и немного его перепишем, сделаем так, чтобы UserService передавался из контейнера и инициализировался без моего участия.

**Заменяем жесткую связанность на интерфейс:**

```
class UserController extends AuthenticatedUserController 
{  
    protected $userService;

    public function __construct(UserService $service) 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->userService = $service;
    }
}
```

**Определяем контейнер при инициализации приложения:**

```
$container = new Injection\Container();

$container['userService'] = $container->factory(function ($c) {
    return new UserServiceImpl(new DoctrineUserRepository());
});

$container['UserController'] = $container->share(function ($container) {
    return new UserController(
        $container['userService']
    );
});
```

Естественно в роутере определяем, что **UserController** нужно брать отсюда. Приложение само создаст класс и будет с помощью него обрабатывать входящие запросы. Только процесс инициализации знает о контейнере, все остальные даже не подозревают что он существует. К сожалению, чтобы соблюдать такое правило, нужно время, а это и есть плата за абстракции и гибкий интерфейс. Вероятно, в начале этапа проектирования, вы будете подставлять десятки зависимостей и просто запутаетесь - это нормально.

В идеале, **приложение вообще не должно знать дальше инициализации про этот контейнер.**

Конечно, иногда нужно поработать в методе контроллера с новым объектом, а создавать новый контроллер не хочется, так как в текущем уже зависимостей тьма, то можно допускать работу с контейнером в контроллерах, конечно, но знайте, когда вы начинаете использовать контейнер в контроллере даже через интерфейс, вы опять получаете минусы локатора, хоть и на уровне контроллеров, и теряете возможность проводить модульное тестирование класса без **конфигурирования DI** сервиса (надо искать сервисы в контроллере) перед началом теста и узнавать явные зависимости, хотя при интерфейсах достаточно было бы посмотреть заголовок и передать их.

Про обращение к global забудьте определенно - глобальные переменные это зло.

[Пример контейнера в Lavarel](http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/container)

Comment: В первую очередь хочу поблагодарить за внимание.Это хороший, развернутый ответ. Но здесь раскрыты общие вопросы, самые очевидные для меня. И у меня остались вопросы, из-за чего меня скорее всего заминусуют, но я считаю что нужно спрашивать то, что не понятно, а не делать вид что все ясно, только что бы не показаться глупым. Их несколько и они достаточно конкретные. Вы мне ничего не должны, но я очень надеюсь на то, что вы найдете время ответить на все вопросы. Их не так много, я думаю около 4-6. Помните что помогая разобраться с этим мне, вы помогаете всем, кто догуглился до этой страницы

Comment: Для начала. Я правильно понимаю, что контроллер описывает действия пользователя? Например, если пользователь хочет посмотреть новости, его запрос преобразовывается во что-то вроде `(new ArticleController)->showFeed()`, где метод `feed` **достает данные из моделей**, передает их в объект представления и вызывает у него метод, отображения данных в форматированном виде? Этот вопрос не по теме, просто хочу убедиться что правильно понял то, что вы имели в виду описывая `UserController`

Comment: @Петр, абсолютно правильно, существует схема разделения данных приложения MVC, в которой контроллер (С) интерпретирует действия пользователя. Его основная функция — вызывать и координировать действие необходимых ресурсов и объектов, нужных для выполнения действий, задаваемых пользователем и соответственно вернуть ответ при необходимости.

Comment: Напишу следующий вопрос сразу, что бы вы сразу смогли прочитать все и эффективно ответить. Меня интересует возможен ли код, в котором не существует неявных зависимостей? Не будем обсуждать целесообразность, просто скажите, возможно это или нет. И если да, то как в этом случае выглядит создание объекта внутри другого объекта. Ведь если класс обязан знать имя класса или его абстракции (интерфейса) то это уже неявная зависимость. Допустим мы используем DI. В этом случае, что бы создать объект вы должны сделать так: `(new Injector)->create('className')`. Всё, класс зависит от Injector. Выхода нет?

Comment: Тут можно было бы предложить передавать объект инъектора в конструктор, но вы должны понимать, что в реальном проекте классы превратятся в питоноподобные, где первым аргументом в конструкторе всегда требуется объект инъектора, что делает код неудобным для человека (как обязанность создавать интерфейсы для любых объектов, даже для тех, которые подразумевают единственную реализацию), а значит трудно поддерживаемым. Или разрешить обращение к global, но в этом случае зависимость лишь перекладывается на имя переменной, а не класса + анти-паттерн

Comment: @Петр Обновил ответ

Comment: Смотрите в чем проблема моего непонимания. Я не знаю как создать объект внутри метода, а не как получить зависимости. А в ответ на мои вопросы (возможно я не правильно их задаю) всегда отвечают о том как внедрить зависимости, но никогда не отвечали как создать объект внутри метода. Вернемся к `UserManager` и `User`. Представьте что у нас всего 2 класса. `UserManager` самодостаточен и ему не нужны зависимости. Но `(new UserManager)->getById(1)` возвращает буквально следующее: `new User(1)`. Я считаю что `UserManager` неявно зависит от `User`.

Comment: Потому что если имя класса "User" изменится, класс перестанет работать. Вы могли бы сказать "Если это зависимость, передавай в конструктор `UserManager ` это имя класса". Но как я уже сказал выше, в этом случае все классы, которые подразумевают создание, внутри одного из методов, объекта, превращаются в питоноподобные. С другой стороны, наверное в языке не просто так предусмотрена конструкция `ClassName::class`. Другого решения нет? Просто, согласитесь, это выглядит странно: `(new UserManager(User::class))->getById(1)`. Да, всё будет будет скрыто в DI, но чувства перфекциониста разбиты.

Comment: Только не подумайте что я издеваюсь. Я имею в виду, вы реально должны теперь указывать как зависимости всё. Ваш класс может создать объекты 2 разных классов и для его работы требуется 1 объект (например, базы данных)? Это значит, что класс зависит от 3х сущностей и его конструктор выглядит теперь так: `function(string $userClassName, string $colorClassName, DBInterface $db)`. Раздуто, а ведь тут по сути только одна реально необходимая зависимость - БД. Если выхода нет, то является ли решением допущение таких жестких привязок в случаях, когда подмены не предвидятся? Или это ведет к сложностям?

Comment: Или в таких случаях нужно передавать в конструктор какую-то фабрику, которой и доверять создание объектов, потому что если класс может столько всего создать, то он скорее всего работает вне своей ответственности? В этом случае методы создавали бы объекты так: `$this->factory->makeUser(1)`, а фабрика определяла бы какие объекты нужно создать. Или такие действия являются попыткой скрыть сложность класса и количество его зависимостей?

Comment: @Петр, вы хотите создать абсолютно независимый код, но это невозможно в правильном проектировании. Вы не должны передавать все, как зависимость. Я хочу, чтобы вы поняли, что нет ничего плохого зависимостях, если они направленны внутрь. User в конкретном случае - это domain уровень, без которого существование проекта не представляется. UserManager не может существовать без User, так как UserManager - это вариант использования. Взгляните на картинку, все что ближе к центру критично, но менее изменчиво, все что дальше от центра, менее критично, но более изменчиво.

Comment: @Петр Почитайте, пожалуйста, еще раз мой ответ с самого начала. Мы должны избегать зависимость только от неустойчивых компонентов и работать только с интерфейсами, а Domain уровень таким не является. Это нормально, что у вас UserManager создает User - это очевидно по его названию. Если имя класса User поменяется - это уже будет совершенно другой класс и другими вариантами использования. Слишком высокий уровень абстракции несет больше проблем, чем вариантов решений. Здесь есть тонкая грань и нужно точно знать, за что вы хотите платить сложностью, чтобы легко это изменить в будущем.

Comment: Предположим, другое дело, когда у вас есть PaymentService, который принимает интерфейс PaymentApi, который может в любой момент поменяться. Ведь, мы очевидно знаем, что сервис может закрыться, или его разработчики захотят внезапно изменить интерфейс или еще хуже - модель работы. Это логичная абстракция от зависимости, так как мы знаем вариант, при котором это может случится и как подменить это в случае необходимости. А вот корневой уровень (User, и т.д) просто так подменить не получится, так как - это основа приложения, ее фундамент, приложение не может существовать без бизнес-правил.

Comment: Хорошо. А что, если некий класс захочет создать и вернуть PaymentService? Как он должен это делать? Понимаете в чем суть? Я хочу узнать, как методы должны создавать объекты, когда это не главная цель класса. Вы воспринимаете пример с User буквально и говорите что это слишком фундаментально для абстракции. Аналогичный пример: перед вами задача - у вас есть `MyClass`, метод `Foo` которого, должен вернуть `PaymentService`. Как поступите? Думаю после этого примера мы поймем друг друга, так как тут ещё и зависимости есть. Будете создавать объект через ServiceLocator? Можете даже просто код написать

Comment: **Здесь важно направление потока управления**. Если вы хотите создать PaymentService в классе MyClass, мы должны знать, что PaymentService зависит от интерфейса PaymentApi, а PaymentApi зависит от конфигурации и реализации, а класс MyClass должен в конструкторе иметь интерфейс PaymentApi и создаваться контейнером и соответственно MyClass должен куда-то Inject'иться, например в контроллер. Ничего страшного, что MyClass создает произвольный класс в методе Foo и что есть жесткая связка с конкретным классом, главное чтобы мы знали что он нам вернет и соблюдали направление зависимостей.

Comment: Что бы все было наглядно, предлагаю вам [код](https://repl.it/repls/WellmadeShyAdaware). Можете изменить его и в комментарии оставить ссылку как вы бы решили задачу. Сейчас я поступил бы [так](https://repl.it/repls/DenseMustyComputergraphics). Класс `MyClass` имеет неявную зависимость от `PaymentApi`. По вашему это допустимый код или что-то не нравится?

Comment: Я бы реализовал это примерно следующим способом: https://repl.it/repls/EasyShabbyConnections

Comment: Немного раздуто для примера. Я правильно понял, что вы создаете `Payment` в `MyClass` через "сервис-локатор" `DoctrinePaymentRepository`? И `MyClassImpl` явно зависит от интерфейса `PaymentRepository`, который в примере реализует класс `DoctrinePaymentRepository` и таким образом, `MyClass` может создавать объекты любого класса, через посредника (локатора), если он их поддерживает? И ещё один вопрос: если я всё понял правильно, обязательно ли создавать отдельный "сервис-локатор" для каждого класса которому он требуется или можно использовать один контейнер, который знает о том как создавать всё

Comment: Нет. DoctrinePaymentRepository - это слой работы с БД связанный моделью с Payment, который является конкретной реализацией уровня репозитория ORM Doctrine, а вот PaymentRepository это интерфейс системы через который она общается с репозиторием и имеет в данный момент метод Create, который описывает лишь возможность создания элемента в БД, и относится к работе с Product. MyClassImpl хочет создавать свой paymentService (представим что их несколько) и хочет быть по сути обработчиком этого сервиса, естественно независимо от представленного API и конфигурации. Схема в ответе и код примерно похожи.

Comment: Естественно, этот класс жестко связан, мы захотим передать другой обработчик, поэтому есть интерфейс MyClass. В большинстве случаев используется один контейнер и этого достаточно для конфигурирования зависимостей, которые будут использоваться приложением. Код нужно понять, вам потребуется время на его анализ. Почитайте про паттерны Repository, Facade, Factory, Мне тяжело вам рассказать все ньюансы. Начните с литературы, которую я указал в ответе, она вам поможет и знайте что нет единственного верного решения - все решения имеют плюсы и минусы, надо лишь знать где чем-то можно пожертвовать.