# Как называется представленное внедрение зависимостей?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Читал [vk-php-sdk](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk), стало интересно как называется тип внедрения зависимостей через использование `use`, представленный [здесь](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk/blob/master/src/VK/Client/VKApiClient.php)

```
use VK\Actions\Account;
class Foo {
    function __construct() {
        $this=>foo = new Account;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Не стоит брать в пример этот код для разработки. Обратите внимание на: "This library has been created using the VK API JSON Schema" Скорее всего, это результат кодогенерации.

Comment: @vp_arth что в ней не так? Строчка говорит только о том, для чего была создана эта библиотека

Comment: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk/tree/master/scripts

Comment: Эта ссылка мне ни о чем не говорит

Comment: Там лежат три скрипта кодогенерации всего остального. Я ни на чём не настаиваю, просто считаю, что не стоит равняться на сгенерированный код.

Comment: А, не увидел "Скорее всего, это результат кодогенерации". Нет, это написано вручную, для взаимодействия с [API](https://vk.com/dev/manuals). А [вот тут](https://vk.com/dev/json_schema) описано, что такое JSON Schema

Comment: @vp_arth сейчас прочитал описание JSON Schema, скорее всего вы все же правы и эта библиотека действительно была сгенерирована автоматически

Comment: В вопрос стоит вынести фрагмент кода, чтобы было понятно о чём конкретно идёт речь. Особенно, если код по ссылке изменится.

Comment: @AK редактировал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные способы действительно можно определить:

1. **import/use** - Это статическое подключение. Импорт выполняется во время компиляции.
2. **DI** - Это динамическое подключение. Выполняется во время исполнения.

Как правильно заметил @vp_arth, import действительно не имеет ничего общего с внедрением зависимостей, по сути данная операция была придумана для обеспечения возможности ссылаться на внешнее абсолютное имя по псевдониму. Предположим, у вас много классов с названием **Manager**, которые имеют длинный путь в пространстве имен, хотя вы точно знаете, что один Manager - это **UserManager**, а другой **TransactionManager**. Так код будет выглядеть намного понятнее.

Да, действительно, класс можно "подменить" подобным способом, но это не приносит решения проблемы, для которой было придумано внедрение зависимостей, [описанное впервые Мартином Фаулером](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). У вас остается такая же по сути жесткая связанность, просто вместо замены названия класса во многих местах класса, вы меняете название класса в одном месте файла. Вы захотите в каких-то местах заменить этот класс на другой, и будете это делать во многих файлах, вероятность ошибки высока в рамках большого проекта с модулями, чем при замене в одном месте.

Каждый класс должен быть сосредоточен на конкретной задаче и не должен заботиться о разрешении своих зависимостей - это определяет принцип единственной ответственности. **Роберт Мартин**, в одной из своих книг "**Чистая архитектура**", определяет данное понятие следующим образом:

> У класса должна быть только одна причина для изменения

Естественно, эта причина должна быть в функциональности который он предоставляет. А зависимости он только определяет, **но не добывает их**. Обеспечение его всем необходимым для работы это отдельная задача.

Проблема в том, чтобы создать слабосвязанный  код, **мы должны зависить от интерфейса**, а не от конкретной реализации. Благодаря подходам динамического подключения, мы можем подменять компоненты на требуемые и получить еще и хорошо тестируемый код. А вот внедрение зависимостей через import не позволяет нам подменять в другом классе соответствующие зависимости, нам требуется вносить изменения в код, потом запускать тесты и откатывать изменения обратно для production, так как способов подмены import просто нет на уровне кода.

Главная особенность, что внедрение зависимостей позволяет принимать решения во время выполнения, а не во время компиляции.

Например, в представленном вами коде (по ссылке ***VKApiClient***) нет возможности подменить внутренние классы простым способом, но наверное оно там и не надо. По сути, данный код так реализован, чтобы не загромождать основной класс кучей методов, и не превратить его в God Object.

В таком случае, мы имеем конкретные реализации классов, а не абстрактные.

---

[PHP. Использование пространств имен: импорт/создание псевдонима имени](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Первым ответил @vp_auth, но в его ответе нет самого важного - аргументации, ответа на вопрос "почему не является?". Приглашаю вас в [мой другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823087), если есть желание помочь мне разобраться с этой темой до конца

Comment: @Firepro, согласен со всем, кроме последнего абзаца. Это всё же, наверное, не стоит называть фабрикой, ведь это простое хранилище объектов с ленивой инициализацией. Инстанциация объекта происходит только при первом вызове метода.

Comment: @vp_arth Да, действительно, спасибо за замечание, я почему-то при первом просмотре не заметил ленивой инициализации в методах.

Answer (score 5):

Ни о каком внедрении зависимости там речь не идёт.

`use X\Y\A` - это просто импорт(псевдоним) полного именования класса для упрощенного использования ниже (`A` вместо `X\Y\A`).

---

Если речь о многократно использованном паттерне ниже:

```
/**
 * @return Account
 */
public function account(): Account {
    if (!$this->account) {
        $this->account = new Account($this->request);
    }
    return $this->account;
}
```

Этот шаблон называется "Ленивая загрузка". Его смысл в том, что необходимый объект создаётся в тот момент, когда он нужен. В данном случае, если клиентский код вызвал метод получения объекта `Account`.

[Отложенная инициализация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Ничего подобного. При помощи псевдонимов можно подменить любой класс. Например `VK\Actions\Account` из примера можно заменить так: `use Foo\Bar use Account`, не меняя при этом класс

Comment: DI подразумевает отсутствие необходимости редактировать файл класса. В вашем сценарии, таки придётся исправлять use.

Comment: Вы придумали это на ходу, об нигде не сказано. Если в вашей реализации этого принципа такой механизм, ещё не значит что он обязателен для всех реализаций механизма внедрения зависимостей

Comment: Если мне для подмены реализации придётся редактировать что-либо в вендорских файлах вашей библиотеки - я не буду этого делать, потому что не хочу терять возможность получить  получить её обновления. Если зависимость не получится обойти другими средствами, скорее всего, придётся отказаться от библиотеки.

Comment: Это хороший аргумент, он объясняет минусы такого подхода (нельзя произвести подмену вне файла класса). Но это все ещё остается способом внедрения зависимостей и мне все ещё интересно узнать каким термином принято это обозначать, для быстрого описания при обсуждении. Но вы, видимо, не хотите признать то, что у любого подхода может быть несколько различных реализаций и признаете только то, чем пользуетесь сами, поэтому вряд ли сможете подсказать название

Comment: Вы набрасываетесь на меня с какой-то странной критикой и непонятно за что. Высказываете утверждения на грани оскорбления... Не надо так. Просто дождитесь другого ответа.

Comment: Понятие "паттернов проектирования" возникло только потому, что программистам нужен был общий язык, общая терминология для одинаковых решений. Как ноты у музыкантов. Так вот алиасинг - это не DI. Не нужно утверждать, что нота ля иногда может быть немножко нотой си. В другом языке - пожалуйста, но не в общепринятом.

Comment: Очень жаль что конструктивное "вы не правы" подкрепленное фактами, воспринимается вами как оскорбление. Но я все понял и больше не буду комментировать ваши ответы, пытаясь исправить что-то

Comment: Это зря, комментировать нужно и важно. Я просто указал на необоснованность вашего "видимо не хотите признать". Хочу! Но пока не могу, недостаточно аргументов.

Comment: "Возможность подмены псевдонима не является полноценным внедрением зависимостей, как минимум потому что вразрез с описанием, не делегирует заботу о построении требуемых ему зависимостей внешнему механизму", видимо вы хотели донести до меня это. Если это так, редактируйте свой ответ, дополнив информацией о том **почему** "ни о каком внедрении зависимости там речь не идёт" или копируйте скобки, если со всем согласны и я отмечу это как ответ

Comment: @Петр когда  я задаю вопрос на so - я стараюсь побольше слушать и поменьше говорить. А уж если говорить резко и безапелляционно, додумывать вещи - то вряд ли можно рассчитывать на то, что с вами будут хотеть вести диалог. (Аналогия. Я видел людей, которые прямо-таки дышат матом, но удивляются, когда обратить их внимание на этот факт.) Вы наверное думаете, что вы конструктивно говорите и апеллируете фактами. Это не совсем так.

Comment: По вопросу. Есть несколько паттернов DI, но некоторые настолько плохи, что это даже вынесено в название (bastard injection). Этот же способ настолько вдалеке от хороших практик, что я даже и не уверен, что на него найдётся название кроме общего "г..нокод" (я не про ленивую загрузку). Почему тогда не считать за DI возможность патчить байткод DLL в ОЗУ, подменяя классы в рантайме? Старайтесь пользоваться хорошими практиками, а не ориентируйтесь на плохие.

Comment: @Петр Пожалуйста, соблюдайте правило ["Будьте дружелюбны"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Ваш прошлый комментарий удалён именно из-за того, что был невежливым. Даже если вам напишут самый некомпетентный совет с кучей неверных сведений, это не даст вам права писать к нему грубые комментарии.